Pre-specifying Random Effect Covariance Matrix in glmer
I need some help with manually specifying a random effect using glmer similar to how it's done in a brm model. In this brm model, Scott Claessens used a pre-specified covariance matrix for a random effect like this:
# load full linguistic distance matrix
linDist <- read_xlsx("data/networks/2F Country Distance 1pml adj.xlsx") %>%
  select(-ISO) %>%
  as.matrix()

# rows and columns identical in symmetrical matrix
rownames(linDist) <- colnames(linDist)

# subset to only OECD countries
linDist <- linDist[oecd, oecd]

# nation's distance from itself is zero
diag(linDist) <- 0

# normalise between 0 and 1
linDist <- linDist / max(linDist)

# convert to linguistic proximity
linProx <- 1 - linDist

# fit bayesian regression with covarying random effects
m2.2 <- brm(y ~ x + (1 | gr(country, cov = linProx)),
            data = culturalSimData, cores = 4, seed = 2113,
            data2 = list(linProx = linProx),
            prior = c(prior(normal(0, 1), class = Intercept),
                      prior(normal(0, 1), class = b),
                      prior(exponential(2), class = sd),
                      prior(exponential(2), class = sigma)),
            control = list(adapt_delta = 0.999))

I want to use the same file data/networks/2F Country Distance 1pml adj.xlsx. Assume that I have the same countries in my dataset.
